# How to pass continuous data from activity to adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Here i am trying to update progressbar from activity class to the adapter class.
For this i need to pass int(continuous changing) to the adapter class.
Might be this question is repeated but many user ask to make interface to call and retrieve data.
But i dont know how to work with it.

Location of below code
Activity..Asynctask...doINBackground..

```java
filepath.putFile(URI).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progressIndouble = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

String id=a getTxt().toString();// this data is identification string to get position in list//
int progress=(int)progressIndouble;
                            // this variable i need to pass in adapter
                        }
                    });
```

Adapter class

```java
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewholder.progressbar.seProgress(retrieve data from activity)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you use following data structure to display in your list:

```
class ProgressHolder {
    public int progress;
}
```

And in onProgress:

```
@Override
public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    ...
    // Update data in your list,
    // if your data structure is immutable don't forget to set new list to adapter
    adapter.progressList.get(position).progress = progress; 

    // I used notifyDataSetChanged for simplicity,
    // but you can use notifyItemChanged or DiffUtils
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

Comment: Uploading task is from activity. Not from onbindviewholder

Comment: But how does it contradict my example? It doesn't matter where you upload your data, you need to update your list data and notify adapter about it.

Comment: I dont have position in activity and I have only one string which can identify the position of viewholder, so can i determine the position of adapter by one string which is available in model class.

Comment: Then how do you want to update specific item in your list if you don't have position? You need to determine position somehow.

Comment: Yes i need position...for example i have student id and can i get its position ?visit image https://images.app.goo.gl/AecmPst9rrzJsZBv6

Comment: Yep, just find position of the student in list by id or by object. It's up to you how to get the position. Sorry, but you don't provide enough data to say how to get the position in onProgress callback. You need to find the way to match callback updates with data you want to update. If you have only one element with progress, then just update. But who knows? I can only guess.

Comment: Please check corrected questions .I set one string in onProgress callback for position.

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking about `Adapter`, I'm assuming you are using a `ListView`, and you want to update the progress of one of the Items in the `Listview`. Also, there should be a `List` in your adapter to maintain the progress of each Item. Below is the pseudo-code to achieve it.

In your Adapter you should have code similar to this

```
public void updateProgress(int progress, int itemPos) {
    list.get(itemPos).progress = progress; // update the data in your list
    notifyItemChanged(itemPos); // This will trigger a call to OnBindViewHolder
}

@Override
pubic void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder viewHolder, int position) {
    int progress = list.get(position).progress;
    viewHolder.progressBar.setProgress(progress);
}
```

Now, call updateProgress() from your Activity, which will take care of updating data in your list and refreshing the Item.

Comment: Ok, but in progressListener i have only progresses variable, how do i find position variable, and i have also one identification string which is available in adapter